# Is there a way to get the dataset's multiple values?

Tags: javascript, dataset

```
<input type="file" data-custom="file" data-custom-icons="i-file i-upload" />
```

I wanna get the value of `data-custom-icons`, but separate them with space.

```
// PREFERRED OUTPUT: ["i-file", "i-upload"]
```

I know how to basically get the value itself and tried to make them in an array via `Array.from()` like I did with the `classList`. But when I do it for that dataset my output is per letter object.

```
var icons = el.dataset.customIcons;
console.log(icons);
var ic = Array.from(icons);
console.log(ic);

// WRONG OUTPUT: ["i", "-", "f", "i", "l", "e", " ", "i", "-", "u", "p", "l", "o", "a", "d"]

// Converting the classList in to an object
var cl = Array.from(el.classList);
console.log(cl);
OUTPUT: ["btn","btn-primary"]
```

Was there a reason why the dataset is behaving that way?

Comment: Use the `split` method. Like this: `var ic = Array.from(icons);` => `var ic = icons.split(" ");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you need to use the `split()` method with the desired delimiter:

```js
console.log( document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').dataset.customIcons.split(/\s+/) );
```

```html
<input type="file" data-custom="file" data-custom-icons="i-file i-upload" />
```